# Error when trying to compile with sourceCpp in R

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am a newbie in C++ and the package Rccp but I found some code in rcpp's gallery that lets you generate from a multivariate normal distribution. The code is

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat mvrnormArma(int n, arma::vec mu, arma::mat sigma) {
   int ncols = sigma.n_cols;
   arma::mat Y = arma::randn(n, ncols);
   return arma::repmat(mu, 1, n).t() + Y * arma::chol(sigma);
}
```

Saving it in the file multivgaussian.cpp, when I try to compile it in R with

```
sourceCpp("multivgaussian.cpp")
```

I get this error message

```
Error in dyn.load("/tmp/RtmpGoFAwi/sourcecpp_6a751b6a3bee/sourceCpp_67198.so") : 
  unable to load shared object '/tmp/RtmpGoFAwi/sourcecpp_6a751b6a3bee/sourceCpp_67198.so':
  /tmp/RtmpGoFAwi/sourcecpp_6a751b6a3bee/sourceCpp_67198.so: undefined symbol: _ZN4Rcpp8internal14r_vector_startILi13EEEPNS_6traits12storage_typeIXT_EE4typeEP7SEXPREC
```

I also tried to see what will happen (in the terminal) if I try to compile it.

```
R CMD SHLIB multivgaussian.cpp
g++ -I/maths/R/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -c multivgaussian.cpp -o multivgaussian.o
multivgaussian.cpp:1:27: error: RcppArmadillo.h: No such file or directory
multivgaussian.cpp:4: error: ‘Rcpp’ is not a namespace-name
multivgaussian.cpp:4: error: expected namespace-name before ‘;’ token
multivgaussian.cpp:7: error: ‘arma’ has not been declared
multivgaussian.cpp:7: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘mvrnormArma’
make: *** [multivgaussian.o] Error 1
```

It's probably something simple but I couldn't find anything online. Thanks a lot,
Charis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rcpp went through a release this week which requires its user packages to be rebuilt. Make sure your RcppArmadillo is rebuilt as well.

In your `R CMD SHLIB` example you are not telling R about the RcppArmadillo dependency so it cannot work.  In the first example the line

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
```

takes care of that, but you still have your linker issue -- possibly due to version mismatch.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply (@suspectus, @DirkEddelbuettel) I just found out about Rcpp's new release and I have to update the version of R in order to install the new package. I guess that will be it. I have to wait until tomorrow when the university will update my  version of R. Thanks again.

Comment: You do not have to. If you have consistent versions then it should work. Just don't update one of RcppArmadillo and Rcpp but not the other.

Comment: Just did it. Everything seems to be working fine now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I recently run into the same error when compiling a simple Rcpp function that has several for loops in it. While the code was run successfully in Rstudio, it run into the same error of `dyn.load` and `unable to load shared object` when run on an lsf grid.

What I did was specifying a cache directory to compile the function using the `cacheDir` option in `sourceCpp` and `cppFunction`. Worked out very well for me too.